# How could I set column width of protected(or locked) cells in excel using pandas(xlsxwriter)?

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying this but doesn't work.

```
workbook = writer.book
user_input = writer.sheets['user-input-swagger']
locked_format = workbook.add_format()
locked_format.set_locked(True) 
user_input.protect()
user_input.set_column('A:E', None, locked_format)
user_input.set_column(3,4,150)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the full issue but the second call to `set_column()` is overwriting part of the first range:

```py
user_input.set_column(0, 4, None, locked_format)
user_input.set_column(3, 4, 150)
```

This should probably be:

```py
user_input.set_column(0, 2, None, locked_format)
user_input.set_column(3, 4,  150, locked_format)
```

Note: I've converted the range "A:E" to "0, 4" for clarity. The `set_column()` method accepts both.